# How to modify existing custom list item and access its modified value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having one listView with custom tile widget. Every tile is having:

- one Text widget
- one iconButton (onTap => increases the value of text by one).

I want to sum the modified values of Text widgets from every tile.

**Problem** : ListView is dynamic means the tiles may increase. I am maintaining a List for holding the listview items. After insertion of the tile, user can increase the value of text by tapping the iconButton.

As the object of tile is already inserted in the list, I am only able to update the Text widget value on screen on tap of iconButton by using setState().

How to update the value of perticalar tile object into the list?

Please find the simplified code of the problem below:

```
class mainWidgetState extends State<mainWidget> {

//  list of the child widget
  List<ChildWidget> listChildWidget = [];    // <- this needs to be updated when user tap the button

// total of the text value from every list item 
  int totalCount = 0;   

// add child widget to list view 
 void addChildWidget() {
    setState(() {
      listChildWidget.add(ChildWidget());
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Test'),
      ),

     // add a new list item
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            addChildWidget();
          }),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listChildWidget.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new ChildWidget(),
                    );
                  })),

          // view total of the counters
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.slideshow),
              onPressed: () {
                getTotalCount();
              }),
          Text(this.totalCount.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int textValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        // one text
        Text(textValue.toString()),

        // one add button
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                this.textValue += 1;
              });
            })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the question.
1) You don't need to create the ChildWidget in the ListView because you already have the widget in the listChildWidget, so you can simply do:

```
Expanded(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listChildWidget.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new ListTile(title: listChildWidget[0]);
                  })),
```

2) If you want to update the totalCount, you can create a function to increase the value everytime the user tap the icon, example

```
_increaseTotalCount() {
    setState(() {
      totalCount = totalCount + 1;
    });
  }
```

Now, when you create another ChildWidget you've to pass the func

```
void addChildWidget() {
    setState(() {
      listChildWidget.add(ChildWidget(
        increaseTotalCount: _increaseTotalCount,
      ));
    });
  }
```

And when the user press, you just need to call the function

```
onPressed: () {
              widget.increaseTotalCount();
              setState(() {
                this.textValue += 1;
              });
            }
```

You can find the example here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ChildWidget> listChildWidget =
      []; // <- this needs to be updated when user tap the button

// total of the text value from every list item
  int totalCount = 0;

// add child widget to list view
  void addChildWidget() {
    setState(() {
      listChildWidget.add(ChildWidget(
        increaseTotalCount: _increaseTotalCount,
      ));
    });
  }

  _increaseTotalCount() {
    setState(() {
      totalCount = totalCount + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Test'),
      ),

      // add a new list item
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            addChildWidget();
          }),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listChildWidget.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new ListTile(title: listChildWidget[0]);
                  })),

          // view total of the counters
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.slideshow), onPressed: () {}),
          Text(this.totalCount.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() increaseTotalCount;

  const ChildWidget({Key key, this.increaseTotalCount}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int textValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        // one text
        Text(textValue.toString()),

        // one add button
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.increaseTotalCount();
              setState(() {
                this.textValue += 1;
              });
            })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time, Your solution is perfect for the problem I have stated, let me add one more constraint to the problem. **In my real application I require which tile is having what modified counter number**.   So basically onTap of increaseCount button I want to update the value of Text in `List<ChildWidget> listChildWidget = [];`  item.  So That, I can have a loop on the list and fetch all the details of the object.

Comment: If you need to know which element was updated you can pass another variable to the function increaseCount like the index of the element or something like that ;) You can add in the ChildWidget another variable final int index, and when you create you pass the listChildWidget size :D hope it can help you!